# Returning from a function in C++

Tags: c++, return

This question may seem a little bit to broad, because it is a subject that splits into:

### 1. returning *by value*

2. returning *by reference*
3. returning *by pointer*

And I'm not sure that I'll be able to understand without knowing all of the points (1,2 and 3), so providing some useful links would be awesome. I did search for topics like "*returning from functions in C++*" but only found some basic examples where things were presented superficially.

---

1. It is unclear for me **why returning** an *user_defined object* **by value** from a function **does not call the copy constructor**

   - I was expecting `classic constructor` message followed by `copy constructor` to appear, instead just the first one did.

---

```
class X
{
public:
    int val;

    X(int val)      : val{val}     { cout << "classic constructor\n";}    
    X(const X& ref) : val{ref.val} { cout << "copy constructor\n";   }
};

// function returning an object of type X by VALUE
X f()
{
    X a = X{6};
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    X obj = f();
    return 0;
}
```

---

1. The previous question arises after trying to implement the following `operator+` function

   - Each time `obj1 + obj2` is going to execute, this `operator+` function is going to return a `temporary` object by value. Here it should call the copy constructor, but instead, the `classic constructor` is also called.

---

```
X operator+(const X& ref1, const X& ref2)
{
    X var_temp{ref1.val + ref2.val};

    return var_temp;
}
```

---

I feel like I misunderstood how does returning from function works. Maybe you could help me to better understand this.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: I cant help you right now, but maybe this (admittedly long) video helps a bit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwDJGrV3pgM&list=PLqCJpWy5Fohfil0gvjzgdV4h29R9kDKtZ&index=13

Comment: for returning a reference/pointer the main issue that often leads to problems is returning a reference/pointer to an object that is local to the function, because its lifetime ends when the function returns, But you should really concentrate on one question per question. Asking multiple questions at once leads to situations like having a duplicate that answers one but not the others